# Encrypting card data at application layer over TLS (MasterCard)

Tags: encryption, tls, pci-dss

I found an article from [MasterCard's blog](https://developer.mastercard.com/platform/documentation/security-and-authentication/securing-sensitive-data-using-payload-encryption/) stating:

> The transport between client applications and Mastercard is secured
> using TLS/SSL, which means data are encrypted by default when
> transmitted across networks.
>
> In addition to that, some of our services implement end-to-end payload
> encryption. For instance, services dealing with sensitive data like
> cardholder Personally Identifying Information (PII) must comply with
> the Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard (PCI DSS), and to the
> requirement of “encrypting transmission of cardholder data across
> open, public networks”.
>
> > Sensitive information must be encrypted during transmission over
> > networks that are easily accessed by malicious individuals.
> > Misconfigured wireless networks and vulnerabilities in legacy
> > encryption and authentication protocols continue to be targets of
> > malicious individuals who exploit these vulnerabilities to gain
> > privileged access to cardholder data environments. (Page 47,
> > Requirement #4, PCI DSS Version 3.2.1 May 2018)

But The [PCI DSS document](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-2-1.pdf?agreement=true&time=1642165029140) (page 47, version 3.2.1) only says the following:

> Sensitive information must be encrypted during transmission over
> public networks, because it is easy and common for a malicious
> individual to intercept and/or divert data while in transit.

(i.e) Sensitive information transmitted over an untrusted/public network needs encryption, which is satisfied by TLS. Even if data should be encrypted inside the organization's internal network, we can use TLS for each system.

I don't understand why payload level encryption is necessary as MasterCard mentions in the blog. Is MasterCard wrong? or did I not understand something clearly? Is payload level encryption necessary?

Comment: "which is satisfied by TLS" -- PCI doesn't say that. That's your factor that you have added. Mastercard is simply saying that they use different forms of encryption to meet the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples contained in the referenced blog show that not everything gets encrypted, but only the sensitive data. To cite:

```
{
    "action": "ORDER",
    "actionId": "91c693c6-4022-4341-ac6a-27c82f599fd8",
    "encryptedPaymentCard": {
        "encryptedValue": "eyJraWQiOiI3NjFiMDAzYzFlYWRlM(...)==.Y+oPYKZEMTKyYcSIVEgtQw=="
    }
}
```

With such an architecture the business and application logic can be implemented without knowledge of the exact payment data, which means that these sensitive data are still protected if the application server is compromised or if there are security issues which might lead to information leaks. The detailed payment information are only handled at some backend and they are end-to-end encrypted between client and backend, not only between client and application server.

I don't know if this kind of architecture is actually required by PCI DSS, but it surely provides more security than only relying on HTTPS. Because with only HTTPS the data would be available without protection at the application server and might get extracted there in case of server compromise or information leak.

Comment: `these sensitive data are still protected if the application server is compromised`. If application server is compromised, then where the private key would be stored? Wouldn't the attacker be able to decrypt them after compromising server?

Comment: @CyberSrikanth: As I said, the encrypted data are processed by some backend. Backend is not the application server, so backend is not necessarily affected if the application server is compromised. The decryption keys are at the backend, not at the application server.

Comment: The private key will be in the pinpad, and is injected at the factory. The pinpad will be tamper resistant such that if you attempt to open it the private key will be destroyed.

Comment: So All the system in the network should have TLS, right, so attacker in internal network will also won't be able to capture them? And in 1st place how the attacker would gain access to application server, If attacker got access to application server, then public key is served to user by application server, so attacker could tamper it with his own private key.

Comment: @Blake The code isn't matter here, please look at flow of data. TLS has CA in its PKI. That makes it authentic, but in payload level encryption, there is not possible to do proper authentication(of certificate) So we can easily replace public key to perform MITM.

Comment: I'm not talking about TLS. I'm talking about payload level encryption. The pinpad encrypts the card data with the internal key and hands it off the to the application server.

Comment: @CyberSrikanth: First, there is no 100% security or no security at all. An compromise of the application at the server does not mean a compromise of the private key used for the HTTPS certificate. They are elevated privileges needed for this. It is still possible for an attacker to grab the data though since the HTTPS was terminated on the application server. Apart from that the key for the certificate and the key used to encrypt the sensitive payload are independent from each other, i.e. compromising the first does not compromise the second.

Comment: I understand that nothing can be 100% secure. But anything you do for security should have reason to do so. Like hashing password with random salt prevent rainbow table attack. But doing payload level encryption prevent what attack? This is my question.

Comment: @CyberSrikanth: Payload level encryption protects against access to the sensitive payload on successful attacks to the application server. Such attacks might not need to be a full compromise of the server but can also be information leak attacks like Heartblead.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Got it, here application server means the server running web server or reverse proxy and not the actual backend, right? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @CyberSrikanth: Correct, there are different kinds of business logic implement at different parts of the system. The web server does not need to know about the actual payment data, only about things like web sessions, user logins etc. Payment data then get processed at some payment backend.